# How to hide token param from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to add some restrictions on my webpage made in ASPX. The webpage must be viewed by a user only if there is the right token in URL. For example, a valid token would be: `xXxDS`:

```
domain.it/Default.aspx?token=xXxDS // user can see the page
domain.it/Default.aspx // user unable to load the page
domain.it/Default.aspx?token=AaaAA // user unable to load the page
```

Is it possible in someway to hide that `?token=xXxDS` from the URL? So when the page is loaded is loaded with the correct parameter but the URL must be just `domain.it/Default.aspx`

Comment: Yes, you can forward to a copy of the page without the `token` parameter in the URL, after you put the token to be validated in to the session for later use.

Comment: Yes, use the appropriate [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Comment: You can also do it via database i.e. keeping the session information (if the user is logged in or not). And you can manage the authentication via folders i.e. assigning rights over folders in asp.net web projects.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan awesome just tryed to use your sollution and works wonderfully

Comment: Better than Rory's solution is to use history.pushState(…).